# How do I use BizTalk factoid to process this value

Tags: xslt, biztalk

I have inherited a BizTalk application that takes input from a Dynamics CRM change event and uses Inline XSLT in a map.

I am using VS 2013 and using Test Map (where you right click the map in Visual Studio).

I have this input:

```
<ns0:DynamicsChangeMessage xmlns:ns0="http://XXXXXX">
<ns0:entity>entity_0</ns0:entity>
<ns0:operation>operation_0</ns0:operation>
<ns0:userId>userId_0</ns0:userId>
<ns0:Changes>
   <ns0:Change>
      <ns0:Key>gcs_universalcredit</ns0:Key>
      <ns0:Value>true</ns0:Value>
   </ns0:Change>
</ns0:Changes>
```

and I've added this to the existing XSLT:

```
<xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="gcs_universalcredit = 'true'">
         <UniversalCredit>Yes</UniversalCredit>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
         <UniversalCredit>No</UniversalCredit>
     </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I get this output:

```
<ns3:Person mlns:ns3="http://XXXXXX/Schemas/Canonical/Person/1.0" 
xmlns:ns1="http://XXXXXX/Schemas/Canonical/Person/1.0"
xmlns:ns4="http://XXXXXX/Schemas/Canonical/Address/1.0"
xmlns:ns2="http://XXXXXX/Schemas/Canonical/PersonRecord/1.0"
xmlns:ns0="http://XXXXXX/Schemas/Canonical/ProcessHeader/1.0">
<ProcessHeader>
   <Source>DynamicsOnline</Source>
   <ProcessName>ChangeProcessing</ProcessName>
   <ProcessType>Update</ProcessType>
   <ResubmissionCount>0</ResubmissionCount>
   <TrackingId>3920dcdc-99e5-44c7-bd7a-d0039e60f235</TrackingId>
</ProcessHeader>
   <PersonType>
       <ADUserId>NotApplicable</ADUserId>
       <TypeOfPerson>Tenant</TypeOfPerson>
   </PersonType>
   <PersonRecord>
       <UniversalCredit>No</UniversalCredit>
   </PersonRecord>
```

I've looked at the web and tried a variety of expressions for

```
<xsl:when test="gcs_universalcredit = 'true'">
```

but I always get

```
<UniversalCredit>No</UniversalCredit>
```

and never Yes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I've worked it out.

```
<xsl:when test="string(s0:Changes/s0:Change[s0:Key='gcs_universalcredit']/s0:Value/text()) = 'true'">
```